# Largest Fee vs Highest Amount when referring to a monetary (USD) amount

Tags: word-choice

Given an array of dollar amounts called 'Fees,' what is the proper way to refer to the largest number? Is largest fee or highest amount preferred?

Comment: You might also consider "most expensive" depending on what you're trying to convey.

Comment: I was just wondering about this comparing "most volume" and "highest volume".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both terms are valid and I'm not sure either would be *preferred*. Given that you are talking about fees explicitly, I'd lean towards the "largest fee". You might also want to consider the "maximum fee".